# Change alphanumeric sort order on Datatables processing to A-Z, 1-9 order

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

Correct me if I am wrong but it seems like data tables sort alphanumeric fields in 1-9 and then A-Z order. Is there a way to change the processing of ascending order so that it is the reverse.  For example I would want **A1, A3, AA, AZ**
to show up as **AA, AZ, A1, A3**.  I have code in my servlet that does a collections sort on the first character of data retrieved from tables and move numbers higher than the letters but I don't want to do this check on all characters on a field.  It doesn't seem like natural sorting is what I am looking for.

Here is the code I was using:

```
            Comparator<Object> comparator = new Comparator<Object>() 
            {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            A8SPT138 obj1 = (A8SPT138)o1;
            A8SPT138 obj2 = (A8SPT138)o2;

            if (Character.isDigit(obj1.getAccountingEvent().charAt(0))) {
                if (Character.isDigit(obj2.getAccountingEvent().charAt(0))) {
                    return obj1.getAccountingEvent().compareTo(obj2.getAccountingEvent());
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else if (Character.isDigit(obj2.getAccountingEvent().charAt(0))) {
                return 1;
            }

            return obj1.getAccountingEvent().compareTo(obj2.getAccountingEvent());
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(tableData.getRecords(), comparator);
```

Thanks

Comment: "I have code in my servlet that does a collections sort on the first character of data retrieved from tables" - it wouldn't be too much work to extend that to check every character, and it should end up fairly simple. Can you show us that? Or you could write a similar comparator in JavaScript and sort there.

Comment: Numbers before letters is a very natural sorting in any kind of language

Comment: It probably is but then why when I fetch from the table it is showing the letters first and then the numbers.  Is that based on how the database was defined?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a custom sorter function that checks each char of the items. Explanation how it works is in the code comments.

```js
const data = "A1, A3, AA, AZ, A, 3".split(", ")

function sorter (a, b) {
  if (a === b) return 0; // a and b same
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(b[i] === undefined) return 1; // b is shorter so should be first
    if(a[i] === b[i]) continue; // same char proceed to the next char
    const isANumber = (/\d/).test(a[i]); 
    const isBNumber = (/\d/).test(b[i]);
    if (!isANumber && isBNumber) return -1;  // b is a number so it should go after
    if (isANumber && !isBNumber) return 1; // a is a number so it should go after
    return a[i].charCodeAt() - b[i].charCodeAt() // a and b are of the same type so sort by char code
  }
  return -1; // a is shorter than b so should be before b
}

console.log(data.sort(sorter))
```

## Edit:

To make it work with `DataTables` you need to register it as custom sort:

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "letters-over-numbers-asc": sorter,
    "letters-over-numbers-desc": sorterDesc,
} );
```

and then use it on your table:

```js
$('#data_table_test').DataTable({
  order: [
    [0, 'asc']
  ],
  columnDefs: [{
    type: "letters-over-numbers",
    targets: 0
  }]
})
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/2cd5fjk0/305/

Comment: The problem is that I have similar data using a DataTable the order will end up showing up as 3, A1, A3, A, AA, AZ or something close to that.  If I could figure out how to use natural sorting in DataTables maybe that would help.  I am trying to get to output that I mentioned above that goes to an excel spreadsheet to match the order of the Datatables.

Comment: Be aware that the above code not will work in any IE, any Safari released prior to sep. 2016 and so on.

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks for pointing that out. I use babel to take care of backward compatibility but this practice is still not a common thing.